# Right align columns in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text-3, pandoc

I would like to *right* align text in columns in Sublime Text 3 (on Win 8.1, FWIW).

That is, I want to convert this

```
Time    Cash Flow
0   -500
1   100
2   200
3   300
```

into this

```
 Time   Cash Flow
    0        -500
    1         100
    2         200
    3         300
```

with the ultimate goal of this

```
 Time   Cash Flow
-----  ----------
    0        -500
    1         100
    2         200
    3         300
```

This a [simple table](http://pandoc.org/README.html#tables) in [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/index.html). I tried the `alignment` and `AlignTab` packages, but these seem to specialize in aligning some delimiters rather than aligning columns like I need.

Is there some trick to do this? I am also open to a solution that requires vi or Excel.

Comment: Did you see my answer? It should be very easy to adapt it so that the specific use-case you introduced in your question is solved. My example expanded your use case quite a bit, in order to demo the full powers of this approached. You may easily *"loose the sight on the whole wood because of all the many trees"* therefore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is a solution which involves Excel or any other spreadsheet program that is able to export CVS.

---

You have to install a **[newly released third-party filter named "csv2table"](https://github.com/baig/pandoc-csv2table)** (<- GitHub repository) for Pandoc.

It is also available as **[a standalone filter](https://gist.github.com/baig/b69e3146251bd90d12e7)**.

1. Install the standalone filter like this:

   ```
   mkdir ${HOME}/bin

   wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/baig/b69e3146251bd90d12e7/raw/d8c8171fbe0ad5543f8aaf0a134250b29c689e57/csv2table.hs \
     -O ${HOME}/bin/pandoc-csv2table.hs

   chmod a+x ${HOME}/bin/pandoc-csv2table.hs

   export PATH=${HOME}/bin:${PATH}
   ```
2. My preferred installation method however is via **`cabal`**:

   ```
   cabal update
   export PATH=${HOME}/.cabal/bin:${PATH}
   cabal install cabal-install
   cabal install pandoc-csv2table
   ```

Read the **[csv2table documentation](https://github.com/baig/pandoc-csv2table/blob/master/README.md)**.

### What can you do with this filter?

1. You can include an external CSV file into your Markdown by...

   - ...either abusing the *image including syntax* like this:

     `![](/path/to/file.csv)`
   - ...or by abusing the *fenced code block* syntax like this:

     `````
     ```` {.table source="/path/to/file.csv" <list-of-attributes>}
     ````
     `````
   - ...or by directly inserting your CSV lines into the "fenced table section" like this:

     `````
     ```` {.table <list-of-attributes>}
     one,two,three
     1,2,3
     100,2000,55555
     ````
     `````
2. By invoking the filter within the Pandoc command line as
   `--filter=pandoc-csv2table`
   the CSV will be converted to a table in all your output formats.
3. Plus, you can apply nearly all the formatting to the table(s) that is supported by Pandoc:

   - Use the attribute `type="multiline"` to create a `multiline_table`.
   - Use `type="pipe"` to create a `pipe_table`.
   - Use `type="simple"` to create a `simple_table`.
   - Use `caption="My ***important*** caption for this table"` to add a table caption. (This can include markdown formatting.)
   - Use `header="no"` if you want a table without column headers (default value used, if not given, is `header="yes"`).
   - ***Now the feature you want:*** Use `aligns=LRCDR` to order the alignment of columns (left to right) as Left, Right, Center, Default and Right again.

### Example

1. Consider this `my.csv` file:

   `` Time,"*Cash* Flow","Third column"
   0,-500,loooooooooooong data field with many words
   1,*100*,
   ***2***,`2000`,shorte
   **3**,30000,(second line is empty) ``

   (As you can see, I even use Markdown markup for some of the data fields of the CSV lines!)
2. Consider this Markdown, `my.md`:

   `````
    # Headline

    ```` {.table source="./my.csv" aligns="LRCR" type="multiline" caption="Some ***caption***"}
    ````
   `````
3. Run this command to generate Markdown multiline table output from your CSV input:

   ```
   pandoc my.md --filter=pandoc-csv2table -t markdown
   ```

   See this output:

   [image: Screenshot of Markdown output]
4. Run this command to generate PDF output with a multiline table from your CSV input:

   ```
   pandoc my.md --filter=pandoc-csv2table -o my.pdf
   ```

   See this output (screenshot):

   [image: Screenshot of PDF output]
5. If you want to generate *"pipe tables"* with the alignment-indicating colons syntax, you have to modify the Markdown a bit, as well as the command line:

   - ***Modify Markdown*** to include `type="pipe"` in the table formatting options:

     `````
      # Headline

      ```` {.table source="./my.csv" aligns="LRCR" type="pipe" caption="Some ***caption***"}
      ````
     `````
   - ***Modify command line*** to ask for `markdown_phpextra+table_captions` output:

     ```
     pandoc my.md --filter=pandoc-csv2table -t markdown_phpextra+table_captions
     ```

     See the output now:

     [image: Screenshot with <code>pipe_tables</code> output including alignment-"colons"]
6. Of course, this works with all other output formats too!

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution. Pandoc `pipe_tables` require the following format and can handle left, center, and right alignments.

```
| Right | Left | Default | Center |
|------:|:-----|---------|:------:|
|   12  |  12  |    12   |    12  |
|  123  |  123 |   123   |   123  |
|    1  |    1 |     1   |     1  |

  : Demonstration of pipe table syntax.
```

If I separate the columns with pipes `|`, then when I'm done I can

- first align the pipes with the `alignment` package in Sublime Text 3
- then manually add back the colons `:` to get the desired alignment.

This isn't quite as easy as @Kurt's filter (and not anywhere near as robust :) ), but it is fairly straight forward.

Comment: Oh, I mis-understood your question then. I thought you'd wanted an easy way to ***edit*** your text columns in a text editor so they are aligned. I thought you already ***know*** about the different Pandoc/Markdown table formats... My answer showed that you do not ***need*** to manually format in an editor, and that you could tell Pandoc to generate Markdown tables from CSV. -- Anyway, there are more tricks to learn if you read **`man pandoc_markdown`**.

Comment: See also my updated answer. I included an example about how to generate a `pipe_table` with alignment colons.

Comment: BTW, your *"@Kurt's filter"* is an honorable mention, but not factually correct :)   -- I'm not the author of that filter, [Wasif Hasan Baig](https://github.com/baig) is.

Comment: @KurtPfeifle your answer is perfect! It is actually the answer to the question I _should_ have asked! I don't care what it looks like in markdown only what it looks like in pdf. :) And your answer gets me that anyways with `-o markdown`. :) Thanks for the lesson!

Comment: BTW, I didn't recommend `-o markdown`, but `-o somename.pdf`  :)